# DFS-R not working on Server 2012 with Exchange DAG

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-server-2012, dfs, dag

We have 2 servers running a small network.  The goal is to have the 2 servers as HA servers on a low budget.  Therefore we deployed Windows Server 2012 and configured DFS-R which all worked fine.

We then proceeded to deploy Exchange 2010 SP3.  The DFS continued to replicate files between the two servers with no issues.

Once we enabled DAG and added both members the DFS stopped replicating.

At first I attempted to restart the replication using WMIC commands, but this was unsuccessful.  So I removed one of the DFS replication folders and attempted to recreate.  Now when attempting to add members to the DFS I receive the following error...

> The Specified member is part of a failover cluster that is already a
>   member of the replication group.  You cannot add multiple members for
>   the same cluster to a replication group. Existing member: SERVER01
>   Name of cluster: DAG01

I have spent some time trying to over come this but have not been successful and any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: As the error hints, you cannot add multiple members of a failover cluster to a DFS-R Replication group. Documentation of DFS-R and Failover Clustering does not state this outright, but all deployment scenarios for DFS-R on Failover clusters focus on this solution: Configure a clustered service (like a File Server) on the cluster, and add that clustered service as a target folder

Comment: Thanks Mathias, but when I try to configure a clustered service it requests shared storage which I don't have.  All I have is local storage on each server.

Comment: You'll need a thirdparty solution for replication between the nodes if you want a clustered file service without SAN/shared storage. I'm not saying SteelEye is the bomb, but [this how-to outlines it pretty good](http://clusteringformeremortals.com/2011/04/06/step-by-step-how-to-extend-a-traditional-microsoft-shared-storage-failover-cluster-into-a-multisite-cluster-with-hybrid-sharedreplicated-storage-using-steeleye-datakeeper-cluster-edition/)